# Haxeflixel with Neko build, Screen size does not fit

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel, neko

I use Haxeflixel, choose build target Neko and Neko 64.

I coded 1280 x 720 resolution but executed screen is not fit.
change resoulution too.

[image]

I just reinstall my os x yosemite system. is the reason it?
I can not understand this situation

var gameWidth:Int = 1280; // Width of the game in pixels (might be less / more in actual pixels depending on your zoom).

```
var gameHeight:Int = 720; // Height of the game in pixels (might be less / more in actual pixels depending on your zoom).
var initialState:Class<FlxState> = PlayState; // The FlxState the game starts with.
var zoom:Float = -1; // If -1, zoom is automatically calculated to fit the window dimensions.
var framerate:Int = 60; // How many frames per second the game should run at.
var skipSplash:Bool = false; // Whether to skip the flixel splash screen that appears in release mode.
var startFullscreen:Bool = false; // Whether to start the game in fullscreen on desktop targets
```

very default settings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's lime 2.4.4 problem.

download `http://www.openfl.org/builds/lime/lime-2.4.0-6-g837aa96.zip`

and
`haxelib local lime-2.4.0-6-g837aa96.zip` on terminal

see below..
http://community.openfl.org/t/running-openfl-error-on-mac/1409/14

Comment: You don't need to donwload it manually, `haxelib install lime <version>` would do the trick as well. This is the relevant issue on the lime repo btw: https://github.com/openfl/lime/issues/472

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, the problem is that `gameWidth` and `gameHeight` set the game's logical screen size, not the size in pixels of the window that the game runs in.

Try changing the window settings in your project's `Project.xml` file to set the physical size of the window to match the game coordinates and it might start looking how you expect:

```
<!--These window settings apply to all targets-->
<window width="1280" height="720" fps="60" background="#000000" hardware="true" vsync="true" />
```

Comment: yes I do that.. but it is same problem, change to default setting 640x480. it is same again. I try to reinstall entire haxeflixel

Comment: I am unsure then. It could be a bug in your current versions of OpenFL or Lime, especially if the window was being correctly sized before you reinstalled OSX.

Comment: I use latest version of all environment.. i am installing `haxelib install openfl` now

Comment: same problem.. why is it doing